# ASP.NET extending application without source code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to extend some web application, probably in ASP.NET WebPages. Just add one function, a non-framework PHP equivalent would be uploading some `newfunc.php` file

It has the only one problem - I don't have no source code (tried to get it for 3 months), only access to .dlls on webhosting. I can imagine few solutions:

- Creating a wrapper library, which would export same functions as the original DLL + one new function
- Injecting some functions into WebSite.dll (ildasm, add own code, ilasm or even directly?)
- Complete disassembling back into the C# code (don't know if it is (still?) possible, 10yrs back it can be done with Reflector).
- Rewriting whole site (pretty time consuming :) )

First two can reveal problem with routing as the website routing routines would not know about new "page". I don't have much experience with ASP.NET.

Which solution should I use or is there some other way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: I think I'd use something like Telerik JustDecompile (free) or similar to disassemble it (Reflector is quite pricey these Days) and take it from there. However, have a look at how its set up. Perhaps it doesn't involve any in-code routing as such in which case you SHOULD be able to go for either a Wrapper or ildasm-ilasm.

Comment: 1. You can use reflector/justdecompile to de-compile the code and extract the source code and inject your code and rebuild. Second option- Assuming you have   aspx pages with you.. So you can write code directly in aspx.. Though very bad practice

Comment: aspx pages are available. As addresses are like "/cs-cz/Home/Contact", I believe there are some routing involved. So decompiling looks like the only way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this may come too late, but for what is worth, here's my 2 cents.

Disassembling will only be useful if the code was built with debugging information (and the DLL aren't obfuscated).

Other than that, i really depends on the code structure. That will limit what you can do and what you can't.

What i would do is something along these lines:

1. Decompile DLLs and look at the methods
2. Identify the methods you must overwrite, and make them overridable
3. If the class is sealed, remove that attribute
4. Create a class that inherits from the class you need to extend
5. Override the necessary methods and create the new ones
6. New methods should go into a new DLL
7. Recompile disassembled DLLs

Depending on ASP.NET version you may have to change in the ASPX files the codebehind class to point to your new classes.

Hope this helps, it's a messy situation the one you're in :)

Comment: Thanks for tips. 

Yesterday, after a few months, original author finally sent the sources. I will not flag this question for deletion as it may be usable for another users. Thanks again.